# Qt drag and drop between two QListWidget

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistwidget

I've two QListWidget (list1 and list2)

- `list1` should be able to receive items from `list2`
- `list1` should be able to be reorganized with an internal drag and drop
- `list2` should be able to receive items from `list1`

---

```
list1->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
list1->setDragEnabled(true);
list1->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
list1->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
list1->setDropIndicatorShown(true);

ulist2->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
list2->setDragEnabled(true);
list2->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
list2->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
list2->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

I had to put the `list2` on `InternalMove` otherwise the item is not remove when I drag it to the `list1`.

And if i put `list1` to `InternalMove` i can't drop any more on it.

Do I have to write my own drag and drop function to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can extend [`QListWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlistwidget.html) overriding [`dragMoveEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#dragMoveEvent) method like below

```
#ifndef MYLISTWIDGET_HPP
#define MYLISTWIDGET_HPP

#include <QListWidget>

class MyListWidget : public QListWidget {

public:
    MyListWidget(QWidget * parent) :
        QListWidget(parent) {}

protected:
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *e) {
        if (e->source() != this) {
            e->accept();
        } else {
            e->ignore();
        }
    }
};

#endif // MYLISTWIDGET_HPP
```

Inside our implementation we check the source of the drag event and we don't accept (allow) dropping items that come from our widget itself.
If you're using [QtDesigner](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-using-qt-designer.html) you can use *Promote to...* option from the context menu when you right click on the `QListWidget` on your form. You have to enter a name of your new class (`MyListWidget` in my example) and you have to enter a name of new header file, where your class will be declared (you can copy and paste the code above into this file).