# Implement modular drag & drop system for QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

I tried to implement a modular drag and drop system for [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCO7.png), which has a lot of QListWidgets in other tabs.
Currenty, the user is only able to copy the items from the right `QListWidget` (at the button "Tools"). But now I want to implement a simple option to copy all selected `QListWidgetItem`s from any `QListWidget`.

### My plan

1. Drag the selected items out of the `QListWidget`
2. A section with a button named "copy" appears
3. The user drop the dragged `QListWidgetItem`s on the copy button
4. The copy button disappears
5. The result is a `QList<QListWidgetItem*>` with the dropped `QListWidgetItem`s

### The problems

1. (-)
2. I'd need a signal when the drag starts / is called
3. (-)
4. I'd need a signal when the drop starts / is called
5. How to get `QList<QListWidgetItem*>` (or `QListWidget::selectedItems`)?

I want a modular opportunity (for example with a pointer to the `QListWidget`) because I don't want to copy some code. For example, I have 12 `QListWidget`s and for each 3 actions. If I want to change a litte thing, I need to do that 36 times.

Is it possible without subclassing?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591923/qt-drag-and-drop-between-two-qlistwidget?

Comment: 2. when the drag starts, you can use `void QAbstractItemView::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)` 

4. when the drop happened, there is void `QListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)`

Then you can fetch the Mimedata what you previously set `QMimeData *QListWidget::mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items) const`

For the drag and drop see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html